# MikroORM failed to connect to database despite correct username and password

Tags: postgresql, graphql, mikro-orm

I'm following Ben Awad's [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8) on writing a full stack application. I'm using MikroORM with postgres.

I created a database called `tut`, a user called `tut`, then gave that user access to the database. I can verify that the user has access to the db like so:

```
$ su - tut
Password:
user:/home/tut$ psql
tut=>
```

Here's what my mikro-orm.config.ts looks like:

```
import {Post} from "../entities/Post";
import {MikroORM} from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path"

export default {
    migrations: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"),
        pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+.*\.[tj]s$/
    },
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: 'tut',
    user: 'tut',
    password: 'tut',
    type: 'postgresql',
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0]
```

When I attempt to connect to the db in index.ts I get a "MikroORM failed to connect to database tut on postgresql://tut:*****@127.0.0.1:5432" (error code 28P01).

Am I supposed to be running a psql server on localhost? The tutorial doesn't have you do that as far as I can tell.

Comment: The error code `28P01` is 'invalid_password' per [Error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/errcodes-appendix.html).  Best guess is the database user `tut` does not have a password in the database.  The sequence you showed at the top of your question `su`'s  to the OS user `tut` then logs in using a socket with no database password.  Try(as any OS user) `psql -d tut -U tut -h 127.0.0.1` and you will see the password error. Do ``psql -d tut -U tut`  and I'm guessing you will connect.

Comment: To fix either create a database password for user `tut` or figure how to configure `MikroORM` to connect to a socket.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running `\password` in `psql` as tut, thanks @AdrianKlaver